# the css selector :empty for tr td is not working

Tags: css

I have checked some article here, but I just got no answer in my case.
I need the empty content td show no bg-color, and I have css an :empty, but it does not work.

sample code here:
http://codepen.io/bard/pen/aDKiv

Thanks experts.

Comment: Thanks every experts, I didn't know that "&nbsp" is considered a content, but I can't remove it since it is created by the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can achieve it as follows:

```
#wp-calendar tr td.pad:not(:empty) {
    border:none !important;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.04);
}
```

if you want to apply some style in case of empty. try following:

```
#wp-calendar tr td.pad:(:empty) {
   /* some style */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you see the specific selector that totally works in my case.

Answer (score 6):

It is not working as your TD has a blank space in itself. Do not let that '&nbsp' come in TD and it will work as '&nbsp' does not fulfill the condition of :empty

And change the following

```
#wp-calendar tr td:empty {
    background:none !important;
}
```

Comment: You are something helpful for me, but in my case the &nbsp is controlled by the backend system, I can just try css trick to make it work. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `&nbsp;`s anyways, because they are considered non-empty text content. In order to make empty cells invisible, you can also use `empty-cells: hide` for the table element. It has better browser support than `:empty` pseudo-class and may be more universal, because it treats cells with only whitespace characters (regular space, line break, tabulation etc.) in them as empty, while `:empty` requires the element to contain completely nothing (including  whitespace characters) to be considered empty.

See edited example: http://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/xEpDn

Comment: Your idea works, but this case I cant change the calendar system, can only do seek a css trick to solve it. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use this. It is working.

```
table tr td:empty::after { 
    position: relative;
    content: "&nbsp;";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```